# Which sword skin is this?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Can anyone tell me what sword skin this is?

If you right click on the image and *Open image in new tab*, you can see the skin much better.

[image]

Comment: I know the devs don't want us to inspect gear for stats, but I would like an inspect gear feature some day for situations like this.

Comment: Just whisper the person

Comment: @elliotrock you can clearly see I _did_ whisper the player but got no response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a while, but I'm pretty sure it's the [T2 Silvari](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Verdant_weapons) racial style.

They are also random loot drops.